# Html Parser margin is Negative

Tags: html, flutter

I'm  using flutter_html 2.1.1 to parse the HTML page into my app,

my flutter version is 2.5.0-6.0.pre

here is where I call html praser

```
Container(
                          child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Html(
                                data: snapshot.data!.HTML_Data   ?? "",
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
```

and the html content that I'm trying to parase is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .cs3664DBA5{text-align:left;text-indent:0pt;margin:0pt -42pt 8pt -43pt;line-height:1.15}
            .cs63EB74B2{color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="cs3664DBA5"><a name="_dx_frag_StartFragment"></a><span class="cs63EB74B2">test</span></p><p class="cs3664DBA5"><span class="cs63EB74B2">afeafef</span></p><p class="cs3664DBA5"><span class="cs63EB74B2">af</span></p><p class="cs3664DBA5"><span class="cs63EB74B2">eaf</span></p><p class="cs3664DBA5"><span class="cs63EB74B2">ef</span></p><p class="cs3664DBA5"><span class="cs63EB74B2">aef</span></p><p class="cs3664DBA5"><span class="cs63EB74B2">a</span></p><p class="cs3664DBA5"><span class="cs63EB74B2">efafew</span></p></body>
</html>
```

but I'm getting this error

```
The following assertion was thrown building ContainerSpan(dirty):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart': Failed assertion: line 268 pos 15: 'margin == null || margin.isNonNegative': is not true.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in your HTML code you have a style defined with negative margins. Since `flutter_html` is using those values in a `Container` widgets margin, and flutter widgets is not accepting negative values as margin, You're getting the error.

If you want you can override the margin using [style](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#style) provided by `flutter_html` but this will change the way your HTML will look on browser and in your app:

```
Html(
  data: snapshot.data!.HTML_Data ?? "",
  style: {
    'p': Style(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 8)),
  },
),
```

Comment: I'm generating this html automatically so I can't change margin value,
can I solve this in flutter side ?